# Java Primitive conversions in assignment context Long and int

Tags: java

```
Long ll = 102; // Error
Byte bb = 101; // No error
```

Why `Long` assignment is resulting in compile time error while `Byte` assignment is fine?

`Long ll = 102` is resulting in compiler error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long". I assumed compiler will widen of 102 to `long` and then box to `Long`. 
But it is not happening.

But `Byte bb = 101;` is not generating compiler error. Here I guess, 101 is narrowed to `byte` (being non-long integral constant) and then Boxed to `Byte`. 
When there is no problem with narrowing, what is the problem with widening?

Comment: Btw `Long ll = 102L;` would work

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of changing code to avoid compiler error, but I want to understand the compiler behavior.

Comment: BTW Don't use objects/wrappers if you can use primitives, they are simpler and faster.

Comment: This type of code is for exam preparation not for production code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey object wrappers are useful when null is a valid value. I prefer to use it instead of sentinel values such as -1.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio I agree that there are time when you have to use a wrapper e.g. builtin collections, or `null` is a valid option and performance doesn't matter.  In 90% of cases you could use either, in which case I would a primitive as it makes it clear that `null` is not a valid value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [5.1.7 Boxing Conversion of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> - If p is a value of type int, then boxing conversion converts p into a reference r of class and type Integer, such that r.intValue() == p

Because `102` is an integer literal, it's type is `int` and auto boxing will convert it to `Integer` (as the spec says), but an `Integer` can not be casted to `Long`.

Thus when you use a `long` literal or cast the `int` literal to `long` the JLS will use the boxing conversion and the result will be a `Long` object.

This will be fine

```
Long long1 = (long) 102;
Long long2 = 102L;
Long long3 = 102l;
```

The second one

```
Byte bb = 101;
```

works, because of the [5.2. Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

So `101` is a integer literal, but there is an assignment that needs a narrowing conversion (int -> byte) and the value of the `int` is within the `byte` value range. Thus it is representable as the variable type (see spec) and it is converted.

This will **NOT WORK** of course

```
 Byte bb = 128; // can not be represented as the variable type. Thus no narrowing conversion.
```

Comment: auto boxing will convert it to Integer (as the spec says), but an Integer can not be casted to Long. Then how come Integer can be assigned to Byte (Byte bb = 101 is working fine)?

Comment: Not convincing. Byte bb = 128; does not work because of out-of-range value. But when a value within range is given narrowing is working but widening is not working. What is the reason for it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Non long const expressions will be narrowed down as appropriately. But will never widen.

Comment: @user3110711 yes that's it. I update my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 12):

This is happening because you are using `Long` rather than `long`. The Java autoboxing will not both convert from `int` to `long`and then autobox `long` to `Long` in the same step.

Change your code to `long ll` and it will work.

There is no marker in java for `byte` primitives - any value entered within a valid range for a `byte` (-128 to +127) can be treated as either a `byte` or an `integer` depending on context. In this case it processes it as `byte` and then autoboxing is able to work on it.

I'm not sure why the decision was made to have Java work this way. It does seem that byte handling is inconsistent from all the other number types.

Comment: Thanks. This looks logical. So while boxing literals are interpreted based on target type.

Answer (score 6):

1. Auto boxing does not *also* cast; eg it will only auto box a `long` to a `Long`, an `int` to an `Integer`, etc.
2. In Java numeric literals are inherently `int`

So, it should be clear why the assignment to `Long` won't work: an `int` is trying to be cast to a `long` then auto boxed to a `Long` in one step... no go.

However, numeric literals in the range `-128` to `127` may be interpreted as `byte` literals in the right context, so that's why the assignment to `Byte` works.

Comment: Thanks. This looks logical. So while boxing literals are interpreted based on target type.